# How to install/upgrade Lisp libraries on Debian

Tags: installation, lisp, debian, common-lisp

I recently discovered that some of my favorite libraries have been removed from Debian, e.g., [Hunchentoot](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=546100):

> For a while now most Common Lisp projects do not do releases anymore,
>   our plan is to move to proving a cl-build like environment inside debian

I've looked at the mailing lists and Debian Common Lisp homepage and not found anything else mentioning this.

Is there a standard way I'm supposed to be installing/upgrading libraries like Hunchentoot now?  I can ASDF-install it, but now I'm dealing with 2 package systems, with their own verification system, etc.  I'm using Debian specifically to avoid that mess.

The [first question of the ASDF-install FAQ](http://www.cliki.net/ASDF-Install%20FAQ) (which doesn't have a very solid answer) is "After you have installed some packages with asdf-install, how do you keep them up to date? This can be hard to do even manually", so I guess I'm not alone in finding this an unsatisfactory solution.

(Asked here instead of SU or SF because I think it's equally applicable to all three, and SO has the most traffic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On anything but Gentoo (which has a very well maintained Lisp overlay), I would use clbuild for now.  I have the hope that XCVB will be usable soon.

Answer (score 2):

While I still sometimes prefer manual installation, [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) makes this answer more or less obsolete.

---

I basically do everything by hand, and I don't even use asdf-install; just mere asdf. I'm not sure if that's an optimal solution, but for me it works quite well (but I don't use many libs; mostly Weitz' stuff which is usually of very high quality.)

Many people seem to use clbuild these days, at least that's how it seems to me.

[Mudballs](http://www.cliki.net/Mudballs) seemed very promising, but I think there is still no one continuing it.

Comment: I've heard of Mudballs (and one other solution which I can never remember the name of) but you're right that it looks kind of dead.  :-)  I guess I should take a closer look at clbuild.